# DocuSign API - Embedded Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to create envelopes for embedded/captive recipients using SOAP based API calls and generate a token with which a recipient can sign the envelope right after it gets created.
I have followed your documentation but am not able to create token(s) for the embedded signer(s). I am able to create an envelope but while creating the tokens, I get an error 
"Invalid Signature Credentials".

According to your documentation, while creating an envelope with captive recipient,I need to pass in clientuserid for the recipient. I need to use the same clientuserid for the same recipient each time. 
It looks like, I might have created an envelope with a captive recipient before but I am not using the right combination..Recipient name, email address and clientuserid every time I am creating an envelope with captive recipient(s).

1) Is there a way to reassign the clientuserid to the recipient?

2) Is there a way to retrieve the clientuserid for the recipient?

3) From the DocuSign account, how do we check if an envelope has been created with a captive recipient(s)?

4) Do we have to turn any setting on from our DocuSign account to create envelopes with captive recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You might be able to use the Recipient Correction call to update the `clientUserId` for a given recipient, but if that does not work you can always remove the recipient from the envelope, then re-add as an Embedded recipient.

2) To retrieve the `clientUserId` value and other information for your recipients you need to make the following API call:

**Get Envelope Recipient Status**

URI:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

Method:

```
GET
```

Sample Response:

```
{
  "recipientCount":"String content",
  "signers":[{
    "deliveredDateTime": "String content",
    "recipientAuthenticationStatus":{
      "(authentication status result)":
        "eventTimestamp":"String content"
        "status":"String content"
      }
    },
    "recipientId": "String content",
    "clientUserId": "String content",    
    "requireIdLookup": "String content",
    "roleName":"String content",
    "routingOrder": "String content",
    "signedDateTime": "String content",
    "status": "String content",
    "email": "String content",
    "name": "String content"  }]
  }]
}
```

3) I'm not sure if you can check through the DocuSign Console, the API call described above will indicate if a given recipient is captive or not.  If the have a `clientUserId` value defined, they are embedded - otherwise they are a remote signer.

4) Yes, this is a feature that you're API integration would need to include in its account plan.  Talk to your DocuSign account manager for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Do I need to use the same clientuserid for the same recipient every time I add that recipient as a captive recipient? Do my demo DocuSign account have to be enabled to use Captive recipients?

Comment: @user2858740 Your Demo account has "all the features mode" enabled on it, so it will be already setup to do so. Using the same clientUserId will allow the signer to not have to adopt a new signature everytime they sign. So that's workflow dependent. Most of the integrations I see have a randomized clientUserId.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. While creating an envelope into my demo DocuSign account, I am getting an error "Invalid Signature Credentials". I am able to create an envelope with remote recipients fine. How do I correct this error?

Comment: Start a new question for that with your sample request, it's hard to decode without all the data. Also mark Ergin's answer as accepted if this answered this question :)